# Redirect do not work. Redirects to it's original page

Tags: 7, redirection

No matter what, no matter what source to what path. E.g. I have this node/7, so when a link appears somewhere in the website with path to node/7 so when clicked I want this to be redirected lets say to node/3, or frontpage, or external, or anywhere else, doesn't matter, just explain me why does it still open the actual node/7? And no, my frontpage is not set to node/7.

Settings (given urls are just examples):
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which version of Redirect module you are using?

Comment: I tried both latest stable and latest dev.

Comment: I have used redirect module having version = "7.x-1.0-rc1". It is working perfectly.

Comment: How does that solve anything?